# Is there a diffrence of fit on GridSearchCV and Pipeline in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

Maybe this is just a bug or I am really stupid, I wrapped (or better said a colleague wrapped) a Keras model using some Keras transformations also wrapped so we can use the Keras model with the sklearn library.

Now when I use fit on the Pipeline it works fine. It runs and it returns a working model instance. However when I use a GridSearchCV for some reason it fails to do the transforms (or so it would seem) and it gives me the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[11,2] = 26048 is not in [0, 10001)
     [[Node: embedding_4/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_4/embeddings/read, embedding_4/Cast)]]
```

The code looks something like this:

```
vocab_size = 10001

class TextsToSequences(Tokenizer, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print('fitting the text')
        print(self.document_count)
        self.fit_on_texts(X)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print('transforming the text')
        r = np.array(self.texts_to_sequences(X))
        print(r)
        print(self.document_count)
        return r

class Padder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, maxlen=500):
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.max_index = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        #self.max_index = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=self.maxlen).max()
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print('pad the text')
        X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=self.maxlen, padding='post')
        #X[X > self.max_index] = 0

        print(X)

        return X

maxlen = 15

def makeLstmModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(10001, 100, input_length=15))
    model.add(LSTM(35, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model

lstmmodel = KerasClassifier(build_fn=makeLstmModel, epochs=5, batch_size=1000, verbose=42)

pipeline =  [
        ('seq', TextsToSequences(num_words=vocab_size)),
        ('pad', Padder(maxlen)),
        ('clf', lstmmodel)
    ]

textClassifier = Pipeline(pipeline)

#Setup parameters
parameters = {} #Some params to use in gridsearch

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=numberOfFolds, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
gscv = GridSearchCV(textClassifier, parameters, cv=skf, iid=False, n_jobs=1, verbose=50)

gscv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Now the above code fails with InvalidArgumentError, but when I run `fit` with the `Pipeline` it works:

[image]

Is there a difference between `fit()` in `GridSearchCV` and `Pipeline`? Am I really stupid or is this just a bug?

*BTW, I am currently forced to use Sklearn 0.19.1.*

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace and also some sample data so that we can test this. Are you searching for `num_words` in your `parameters`? Is that greater than `10001`?

Comment: The differences in `pipeline.fit()` and `gscv.fit()` will be the different data (pipeline will get full and each part in gscv will get smaller train data from `skf`) and obviously the different parameter combinations to search.

Comment: @VivekKumar I can't share the sample data, but for reproduction, it's simple text classification. You can use any text, label combination to test the code. And yes I use `num_words` to limit the bag of words to 10001. Otherwise, the bag of words is to large. After hours of thinking and debugging, I found out what the problem was. See my answer.

Comment: Well I tried it with sample data, but could not reproduce.  I am not able to see any answer

Comment: Well, you made me think, the next time I will be clearer and provide some test data, or even better a public Jupyter notebook. Thanks for looking into my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of thinking and debugging, I came to the following conclusion:

`Pipeline.fit()` is able to auto fill `**kwargs` arguments.

`GridSearchCV.fit()` is not able to auto fill `**kwargs` arguments.

*I tested this on sklearn 0.19.1*

My issue was that the bag of words created with Keras `Tokenizer` was created using the `num_words` parameter which limits the bag to a maximum number of words. My colleague did a bad job at this hence the number of words matches to the number of input dimensions in the LSTM model. Because the `num_words` were never set, the bag was always bigger than the input dimension.

The `num_words` were passed to the `Tokenizer` as `**kwargs` arguments.

```
class TextsToSequences(Tokenizer, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

For some reason `GridSearchCV.fit()` is not able to fill this automatically. The solution to this would be to use fixed arguments.

```
class TextsToSequences(Tokenizer, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, num_words=8000, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(num_words, **kwargs)
```

After this change `GridSearchCV.fit()` works.